# What would cause a try/catch block to fail exception handling despite execution landing in catch block?

Tags: scala, try-catch

The execution from below code

```
line 108       try 
line 109       {
line 110           columnValCSV = columns_List(fileNumber)(columnNumber)
line 111       }
line 112       catch 
line 113       {
line 114           case e: Exception => println(columnValCSV +"OtherLogText")
line 115       }
```

lands in the catch block as shown in the stack trace.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   10    at Main$.$anonfun$parseSecondDataSource$2(Main.scala:114)   at
>   Main$.$anonfun$parseSecondDataSource$2$adapted(Main.scala:85)     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)     at
>   scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)    at
>   Main$.$anonfun$parseSecondDataSource$1(Main.scala:85)     at
>   Main$.$anonfun$parseSecondDataSource$1$adapted(Main.scala:68)     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:52)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at Main$.parseSecondDataSource(Main.scala:68)   at
>   Main$.main(Main.scala:147)    at Main.main(Main.scala)

However, instead of avoiding throwing an exception as my code is supposed to do, it crashes.

Comment: Maybe that code runs using **Futures** or inside **Spark**. `Exceptions` are not catched across threads / machines. For that reason, usually in Scala we avoided throwing them and instead we use `Try` or `Either` to handle errors.

Comment: No futures/spark. its a simple 100 - 200 line scala object that parses csv and JSON files. Nothing complicated.

Comment: Then it should work, that is weird. Can you give us an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The actual print statement in the catch block references the same variable I put in the try block. That should be the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual print statement in the catch block references the same variable I put in the try block. That was the problem

Answer (score 2):

An exception handler can also throw.

```
scala> try throw null catch { case _: NullPointerException => ??? }
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:347)
  at .liftedTree1$1(<console>:1)
  ... 28 elided
```